# PHP array_merge empty values always less prioritar

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

My goal is to merge 2 different arrays.

I have table "a" & "b".
Data from table "a" are more prioritar.

**PROBLEM**: if a key from "a" contains an empty value, I would like to take the one from table "b".

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$a = array('key1'=> "key1 from prioritar", 'my_problem'=> "");

$b = array('key1'=> "key1 from LESS prioritar", 'key2'=>"key2 from LESS prioritar", 'my_problem'=> "I REACHED MY GOAL!");

$merge = array_merge($b, $a);

var_dump($merge);
```

Is there a way to do this in one function without doing something like below?

```
foreach($b as $key => $value)
{
  if(!array_key_exists($key, $a) || empty($a[$key]) ) {
    $a[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: your array `$b` has 2 `key2` indexes?

Comment: `!array_key_exists || empty` is nonsense. Using either one will do just fine, depending on whether you're interested in a comparison to `false` or not. Using both together is the same as just using `empty`.

Comment: @roullie, thanks, this was a typo

Comment: @deceze, wouldn't it provide a php warning if I do "empty($a[$key])" and that the key doesn't exist?

Comment: No it won't, that's the point of `empty`. [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: @deceze, thanks for the info. I did not remember this point, +1 for your anser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `array_replace` and `array_filter`

```
$mergedArray = array_replace($b, array_filter($a));
```

The result would be:

```
array(3) {
  ["key1"]=>
  string(19) "key1 from prioritar"
  ["key2"]=>
  string(24) "key2 from LESS prioritar"
  ["my_problem"]=>
  string(18) "I REACHED MY GOAL!"
}
```

Comment: Note that `array_filter($a) + $b` will do just fine as well.

Comment: @Matei, thanks a lot. This is (almost) what I was searching for. "almost" because I initially wanted to keep the empty value from "$a" if the key doesn't exist in "$b". But this is already much better than a foreach ;)

Answer (score 4):

Just [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) `$a` which will remove any item with `''` value.

```
$merge = array_merge($b, array_filter($a));
```