# array_merge in PHP not overriding values

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I'm having some strange issue with array_merge.

The 2 arrays I have are as follows;

```
$original = array(
    'details' => array('error' => 0)
    'maxWidth' => 700,
    'maxHeight' => 700,
    'size' => 'original'
);

$defaults = array(
    'details' => array(),
    'maxWidth' => 1024,
    'maxHeight' => 1024,
    'size' => 'original'
);
```

But when i do

```
$merge = array_merge($defaults, $original);
```

It doesn't replace the maxWidth and maxHeight with the updated values of 1024, it keeps them at 700

Any idea how i can fix this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) (emphasis by me):

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then **the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one**.

So currently you start with the values of `$defaults` and override with `$original`. Simply switch your arrays:

```
$merge = array_merge($original, $defaults);
```

Comment: That kills the details in the 'details' part though

Comment: Yes, that's how that function works. If you want to keep your details, do not include them in `$defaults`.

Comment: You could also play around with `array_replace_recursive` or `array_merge_recursive`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34367698/4616087) for a short overview.